# Zero convolution of a function with a measure

Tags: real-analysis, harmonic-analysis

Suppose $0\not=f\in L^1_{loc}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ and $\mu$ is a positive Borel measure with compact support. Given $f\ast\mu=0, $ what can be said about $\mu$?

Comment: This question is a little bit too open-ended I think, but one thing to think about is to instead consider the simpler case of $f \in L^1 \cap L^2$ and $d\mu = g(x) \, dx$ with $g(x)$ a compactly supported smooth function. Then what does $f \ast \mu = 0$ tell you?

Comment: Good point.Well trivial case is when $f$ and $g$ are both non-negative, then either $f=0$ a.e or $g=0$ a.e.Other than that I dont know.

Comment: @BigM: You can Fourier transform. This immediately shows that $\hat{f}$ must vanish on the support of $\hat{g}$. In the setting suggested by Christopher Wong, $\hat{g}$ cannot be compactly supported. I don't know how much more can we say, though.

Comment: Is this true?under right setting $\hat{\mu}=0\Rightarrow \mu=0$

Comment: Yes, the Fourier transform is a [bijection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fourier_transform#Tempered_distributions) of the space of tempered distributions onto itself. A compactly supported measure is a tempered distribution.